# How come I can't add an object to my list in c#?

Tags: c#, constructor

The following results in a NullReferenceException. It tells me that the "drawObjs.Add(drawObj);" - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I don't understand why this is not set to an instance?

**The list:**

```
List<drawObject> drawObjs;
```

**The method which add's to the list:**

```
public void createDrawObj()
        {

            drawObject drawObj = new drawObject(100,100,100,100,10);

            drawObjs.Add(drawObj);

        }
```

**And the class itself:**

```
class drawObject
    {

        float _posX;
        float _posY;
        float _sizeX;
        float _sizeY;
        float _cr;

        public drawObject(float posX, float posY, float sizeX, float sizeY, float cr)
        {

            _posX = posX;
            _posY = posY;
            _sizeX = sizeX;
            _sizeY = sizeY;

        }

        public GraphicsPath objPath() 
        {

            GraphicsPath Path = new GraphicsPath();

            Path.AddLine(_posX + _cr, _posY, _posX + _sizeX - (_cr * 2), _posY);
            Path.AddArc(_posX + _sizeX - (_cr * 2), _posY, _cr * 2, _cr * 2, 270, 90);
            Path.AddLine(_posX + _sizeX, _posY + _cr, _posX + _sizeX, _posY + _sizeY - (_cr * 2));
            Path.AddArc(_posX + _sizeX - (_cr * 2), _posY + _sizeY - (_cr * 2), _cr * 2, _cr * 2, 0, 90);
            Path.AddLine(_posX + _sizeX - (_cr * 2), _posY + _sizeY, _posX + _cr, _posY + _sizeY);
            Path.AddArc(_posX, _posY + _sizeY - (_cr * 2), _cr * 2, _cr * 2, 90, 90);
            Path.AddLine(_posX, _posY + _sizeY - (_cr * 2), _posX, _posY + _cr);
            Path.AddArc(_posX, _posY, _cr * 2, _cr * 2, 180, 90);

            Path.CloseFigure();

            return Path;

        }

        public LinearGradientBrush objBrush(int objColor)
        {

            LinearGradientBrush lgb;
            if (objColor == 1)
            {
                lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(new PointF(_posX + (_sizeX / 2), _posY), new PointF(_posX + (_sizeX / 2), _posY + _sizeY), Color.RosyBrown, Color.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(new PointF(_posX + (_sizeX / 2), _posY), new PointF(_posX + (_sizeX / 2), _posY + _sizeY), Color.GreenYellow, Color.Green);
            }
            return lgb;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to instantiate `drawObjs` - without it, it is a null reference:

```
List<drawObject> drawObjs = new List<drawObject>();
```

Comment: Now I just feel stupid ;) - don't know how I could have overlooked that :)

Comment: @Bildsoe - We all have moments where we look at a problem too closely to see it...

Comment: and give them different names :)

Answer (score 4):

Instansiate your list:

```
List<drawObject> drawObjs = List<drawObject>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used type inference you might be less likely to make this mistake.

```
var drawObjs = new List<drawObject>();
```